# dataframe with nested dataframes : how to set id column with data.table::rbindlist

Tags: r, data.table

given a data.table created from a JSON array :

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(reprex)

DT<- fromJSON("http://data.sensor.community/airrohr/v1/sensor/21523/",flatten=T)

setDT(DT)

str(DT[,.(timestamp,sensordatavalues),])
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ timestamp       : chr  "2019-10-25 18:21:00" "2019-10-25 18:18:33"
#>  $ sensordatavalues:List of 2
#>   ..$ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   .. ..$ id        : num  1.12e+10 1.12e+10
#>   .. ..$ value_type: chr  "P1" "P2"
#>   .. ..$ value     : chr  "10.78" "5.90"
#>   ..$ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   .. ..$ id        : num  1.12e+10 1.12e+10
#>   .. ..$ value_type: chr  "P1" "P2"
#>   .. ..$ value     : chr  "7.10" "5.33"
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

i manage to unested the column containing a list of data.frame's :

```
DTdata <-rbindlist(DT$sensordatavalues,use.names=TRUE)
DTdata
#>             id value_type value
#> 1: 11232984769         P1 10.78
#> 2: 11232984770         P2  5.90
#> 3: 11232945708         P1  7.10
#> 4: 11232945709         P2  5.33
```

but i'm stuck how to add the `timestamp` column from the original `DT` within the `rbindlist` function. Does anyone could enlight me ?

Comment: You can use the `idcol`

Answer (score 1):

We can set the names of the `list` column with the 'timestamp' and make use of the `idcol` argument from `rbindlist`

```
DT[, rbindlist(setNames(sensordatavalues, timestamp), idcol = 'timestamp')]
#            timestamp          id value_type value
#1: 2019-10-25 18:28:25 11233103168         P1  7.95
#2: 2019-10-25 18:28:25 11233103169         P2  4.95
#3: 2019-10-25 18:25:58 11233063825         P1  9.55
#4: 2019-10-25 18:25:58 11233063829         P2  5.62
```

Naming the `list` elements with 'timestamp' can change the 'type' to `character` class (though in this case the input column 'timestamp' is `character`).  If we need to preserve the type

```
rbindlist(Map(cbind, timestamp = DT$timestamp, DT$sensordatavalues))
```